# Use PyLint on Jenkins with Warnings Plugin and Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, pylint

I want to use [PyLint](https://www.pylint.org) on Jenkins with [Warnings Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings-ng/) and [Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/), since Violations plugin is deprecated.

There are no docs or complete examples.

There is [some information](https://github.com/kitconcept/jenkins-pipeline-examples#static-code-analysis):

```
timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES') {
  sh 'npm run lint:ci'
  step([$class: 'WarningsPublisher',
    parserConfigurations: [[
      parserName: 'JSLint',
      pattern: 'pmd.xml'
    ]],
    unstableTotalAll: '0',
    usePreviousBuildAsReference: true
  ])
}
```

and [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347233/jenkins-with-pylint-gives-build-failure):

```
pylint || exit 0
```

Is there a more robust solution?

Comment: The graphs and tables that are displayed are all basic and older style, have you had any luck getting current graphing to work with your configuration ? the ui in Jenkins does not display like this for me : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin

Comment: sorry, I haven't used it for a while now

Comment: The original Warnings Plugin has been superseded by [Warnings Next Generation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings-ng/)

Answer (score 27):

I've managed to get it working:

```
sh 'pylint --disable=W1202 --output-format=parseable --reports=no module > pylint.log || echo "pylint exited with $?")'
sh 'cat render/pylint.log'

step([
        $class                     : 'WarningsPublisher',
        parserConfigurations       : [[
                                              parserName: 'PYLint',
                                              pattern   : 'pylint.log'
                                      ]],
        unstableTotalAll           : '0',
        usePreviousBuildAsReference: true
])
```

I'm still not sure how to configure it.

From what I was able to read from the [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-plugin/blob/ee546a8f9de5dab58925e883c413d34659519696/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/warnings/WarningsPublisher.java#L145) and [tests](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-plugin/blob/ee546a8f9de5dab58925e883c413d34659519696/src/test/java/hudson/plugins/warnings/WarningsWorkflowTest.java#L72), those might be the possible parameters because they are the constructor parameters:

- `healthy` - Report health as 100% when the number of annotations is less than this value
- `unHealthy` - Report health as 0% when the number of annotations is greater than this value
- `thresholdLimit` - determines which warning priorities should be considered when evaluating the build stability and health
- `defaultEncoding` - the default encoding to be used when reading and parsing files
- `useDeltaValues` - determines whether the absolute annotations delta or the actual annotations set difference should be used to evaluate the build stability
- `unstableTotalAll` - annotation threshold
- `unstableTotalHigh` - annotation threshold
- `unstableTotalNormal` - annotation threshold
- `unstableTotalLow` - annotation threshold
- `unstableNewAll` - annotation threshold
- `unstableNewHigh` - annotation threshold
- `unstableNewNormal` - annotation threshold
- `unstableNewLow` - annotation threshold
- `failedTotalAll` - annotation threshold
- `failedTotalHigh` - annotation threshold
- `failedTotalNormal` - annotation threshold
- `failedTotalLow` - annotation threshold
- `failedNewAll` - annotation threshold
- `failedNewHigh` - annotation threshold
- `failedNewNormal` - annotation threshold
- `failedNewLow` - annotation threshold
- `canRunOnFailed` - determines whether the plug-in can run for failed builds, too
- `usePreviousBuildAsReference` - determines whether to always use the previous build as the reference build
- `useStableBuildAsReference` - determines whether only stable builds should be used as reference builds or not
- `canComputeNew` - determines whether new warnings should be computed (with respect to baseline)
- `shouldDetectModules` - determines whether module names should be derived from Maven POM or Ant build files
- `includePattern` - Ant file-set pattern of files to include in report
- `excludePattern` - Ant file-set pattern of files to exclude from report
- `canResolveRelativePaths` - determines whether relative paths in warnings should be resolved using a time expensive operation that scans the whole workspace for matching files.
- `parserConfigurations` - the parser configurations to scan files
- `consoleParsers` - the parsers to scan the console

And the `parserConfigurations` [javadoc](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/warnings/ParserConfiguration.java#L37) says only:

- `pattern` - the pattern of files to parse
- `parserName` - the name of the parser to use

where [the list of the parsers seams to be here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/warnings/parser).

If you have more information or something needs correcting feel free to edit or drop a comment.

Comment: `messagesPattern` - warning messages to exclude from report

Comment: It's incredible how hard it is to find docs on this topic. Thanks a lot for posting this Pawel.

Comment: instead of redirecting output to file and then `cat`ing it to console, you can just use `| tee pylint.log` which will do the same.

Answer (score 13):

Note that an alternative to `|| exit 0` or `|| echo "failed"` (which are fine) is to use `pylint --exit-zero`:

> ```
> --exit-zero         Always return a 0 (non-error) status code, even if
>                     lint errors are found. This is primarily useful in
>                     continuous integration scripts.
> ```

Comment: `--exit-zero` option available from Pylint 1.9.3

Answer (score 9):

## For Declarative Pipeline Syntax

```
sh 'python3 -m pylint --output-format=parseable --fail-under=<threshold value> module --msg-template="{path}:{line}: [{msg_id}({symbol}), {obj}] {msg}" | tee pylint.log || echo "pylint exited with $?"'
echo "linting Success, Generating Report"
recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, aggregatingResults: true, tool: pyLint(pattern: 'pylint.log')
```

It will break the build if the pylint rate is less then the threshold value. And using Warnings Next generation plugin it will create graphs like below

[image]

Comment: This is working for the most part for me. But it isn't failing the build if the threshold is below.
`sh 'poetry run pylint --output-format=parseable --fail-under=9.5 ./src --msg-template="{path}:{line}: [{msg_id}({symbol}), {obj}] {msg}" | tee pylint.log || echo "pylint exited with $?"'`
                `echo "Linting Success, Generating Report"`
                `recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, aggregatingResults: true, tool: pyLint(pattern: 'pylint.log')`

My output from Pylint:
`Your code has been rated at 9.48/10`

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
   stage('Static code analysis'){
        steps {
           sh 'PYTHONPATH=path/to/extended pylint -f parseable --reports=no * > pylint.log' //remove pythonpath if not needed in your environment
        }
        post {
            always {
                sh 'cat pylint.log'
                    recordIssues healthy: 1, tools: [pyLint(name: 'report name', pattern: '**/pylint.log')], unhealthy: 2
            }
        }
    }
```

Jenkins was using this plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings-ng/ for the `recordIssues` step