# Github actions Pylint step unable to create directory with test job

Tags: docker, github-actions, pylint, fastapi

I'm actually trying to finish my first GitHub action with CI/CD and Heroku deploy and a i get this error.

**Error image:**
[image]

This is my public repo.
https://github.com/jovicon/the_empire_strikes_back_challenge
Everything is updated in "development" branch

**This is my test job:** [(full file)](https://github.com/jovicon/the_empire_strikes_back_challenge/blob/main/.github/workflows/main.yml)
Note: When I comment **Pylint step** everything works fine.

```yml
test:
    name: Test Docker Image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Checkout master
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Log in to GitHub Packages
        run: echo ${GITHUB_TOKEN} | docker login -u ${GITHUB_ACTOR} --password-stdin docker.pkg.github.com
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Pull image
        run: |
          docker pull ${{ env.IMAGE }}:latest || true
      - name: Build image
        run: |
          docker build \
            --cache-from ${{ env.IMAGE }}:latest \
            --tag ${{ env.IMAGE }}:latest \
            --file ./backend/Dockerfile.prod \
            "./backend"
      - name: Run container
        run: |
          docker run \
            -d \
            --name fastapi-tdd \
            -e PORT=8765 \
            -e ENVIRONMENT=dev \
            -e DATABASE_TEST_URL=sqlite://sqlite.db \
            -p 5003:8765 \
            ${{ env.IMAGE }}:latest
      - name: Pytest
        run: docker exec fastapi-tdd python -m pytest .
      - name: Pylint
        run: docker exec fastapi-tdd python -m pylint app/
      - name: Black
        run: docker exec fastapi-tdd python -m black . --check
      - name: isort
        run: docker exec fastapi-tdd /bin/sh -c "python -m isort ./*/*.py --check-only"
```

I let here my **Dockerfile.prod** too:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-slim-buster

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# create the app user
RUN addgroup --system app && adduser --system --group app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# set environment varibles
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV ENVIRONMENT prod
ENV TESTING 0

# install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install netcat gcc postgresql \
    && apt-get clean

# install python dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
COPY ./dev-requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r dev-requirements.txt

# add app
COPY . .

RUN chmod 755 $HOME

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER app

# run gunicorn
CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT app.main:app -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `$HOME` directory permissions to 755 from the default user. `chown -R app:app $APP_HOME` targets only `$APP_HOME`, which is only a subdirectory of `$HOME`.

In consequence, the user `app` doesn't have write permissions to `$HOME` and pylint can't create the directory `/home/app/.pylint.d`.

Comment: I tried this:

`Dockerfile.prod
RUN chmod 755 $HOME
RUN chown -R app:app $HOME
`

disapear "unable to create" message but, error line with exit code 30 still there.

[link](https://github.com/jovicon/the_empire_strikes_back_challenge/runs/1215855675?check_suite_focus=true)

Comment: I solve the exit code with this:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54934402/9592769)