# Why does my Jenkins pipeline fail with Error code 24

Tags: jenkins

I'm running a basic pipeline that executes pylint on my repository code.

My Jenkins runs on Debian etch, the Jenkins version is 2.231.

At the end of the pipeline, I'm getting the following error :

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 24
Finished: FAILURE
```

As this page https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+Exit+Status explains, the error code 24 refers to a "too many open files" error.

If I remove the pylint part of the job, the pipelines executes smoothly.

Il tried to configure the limit in /etc/security/limits.conf

```
jenkins soft nofile 64000
jenkins hard nofile 64000
```

and in the Jenkins config file /etc/default/jenkins :

```
MAXOPENFILES=64000
```

If I put "ulimit -n" in the pipeline, the configured value is displayed but it has no effect on the result that remains : ERROR: script returned exit code 24.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from pylint that doesn't return a 0 code even if it ran successfully.

The solution is to use the --exit-zero option when running pylint.

```
pylint --exit-zero src
```

[Jenkins with pylint gives build failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347233/jenkins-with-pylint-gives-build-failure)